# How to intercept I/O port access for purpose of virtualizing hardware

Tags: c++, assembly, hardware, simulation

I am trying to do some simulation. In the real case, an `x86-based` Industrial PC connects with an network board using PC/104. The network board is treated as an I/O device. The code running on `IPC` uses assembly instructions like IN, OUT to access the I/O ports. I want to simulate the whole thing on my laptop.

The `c++` program running on `IPC` can be ported to my laptop since they are both based on x86-architecture. But for IN/OUT instructions, I ran into troubles since no real network board is connected to my laptop. I simulated the logics of the network board using `SystemC`. **I am wondering if there's a way to intercept the I/O port access(IN/OUT) to real hardware and let the logics of the virtualized hardware take over.**

I appreciate any help or advice from you.

Comment: One possible method would be emulating your entire hardware (the PC and all the peripherals). I would try to add a custom device to QEMU.

Comment: Thanks, but that would be too complex for me. Do you think it's possible to only emulate the custom device?

Comment: Which OS are you using on the PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code with IN/OUT instructions is in a user program, you need to find out how to intercept and handle these instructions either in this same program (perhaps, by means of signals?) or in the kernel. IN and OUT are privileged instructions and by default they cause an exception (#GP) in user-mode code and the kernel then handles this exception. You need to have your own handler for this case. In Windows this can be done using so-called Structured Exception Handling (AKA SEH).

If the code is in the kernel already, it's tricky because IN/OUT in there don't cause #GP.

Couldn't you just replace the routines doing IN and OUT with something else, with the calls to the device emulation code? You're emulating it anyway, nobody cares if it's IN/OUT or something else.

See [how this can be done with SEH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814167/968261).

Comment: The code with IN/OUT instructions is in user mode. SO SEH is a good solution. Thanks for that. I prefer not to modify routines using IN/OUT because I want to run exactly the same software stack both in real cases and on virtualized platform.

Comment: I have added a link to an answer to a similar question about printer port virtualization with SEH.